# Creating a navigation on page load (jQuery/Web Design)

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have a project that involves many images, but each user will only be concerned with just a few of the images that are posted.  The current system is organized Year > Month > Day, and I'd like to keep that going in the gallery navigation page.

I could update the gallery navigation page each time a new set of images were added, but I was wondering if I could use jQuery to build the navigation from the existing folder system when the page loads, so that once a new folder of images are added no changes will need to be made to the navigation page.

Comment: can you try to explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to do? Maybe some code would help us understand

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can't do that with jQuery alone. As a javascript library, it runs client side and has per se no access to server's file system.

You need at least an ajax request to (i.e.) a PHP file on the server that will read the file system and create the menu.

That said, you may create the menu before delivering the page and thus saving an ajax request. Within the script you might even cache the dynamic menu and only update it like every hour (adjust to your needs).